# Haskell, how to count all nodes of a tree (pattern matching)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

the question is in the title :)

My Code:

```
data tree a = Leaf a | Node (tree a) (tree a)

treeo = Node((Node(Leaf 1)(Node (Leaf 10)(Leaf 11))))
                (Node(Leaf 12)(Leaf 13))

-- count all leafs: 
lcounter(Leaf a) = 1
lcounter(Node a b)= lcounter a + lcounter b
-- count all nodes?:
```

Comment: If you're using the recent GHC and using Data.Tree, then you can count all nodes in the tree using the length function.

Comment: @GarethR, `Data.Tree` defines rose trees. The tree here is a binary leaf tree. A variant of that technique could be used here by deriving `Foldable` and then calculating the number of nodes from the number of leaves. Can you see how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First notice that data type definitions should start uppercase:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

To count all nodes, it is pretty much already what you did, a simple pattern match over the tree data constructors:

```
countNodes :: Tree a -> Int
countNodes (Leaf a) = 0
countNodes (Node left right) = 1 + countNodes left + countNodes right
```

With your example:

```
let tree = Node((Node (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 10) (Leaf 11))))(Node (Leaf 12) (Leaf 13))
countNodes tree -- 4
```

Comment: Thanks for hint with the data type definition and the code summary!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `countNodes (Leaf a) = 1` (since you probably want to count the leaf nodes as well)?

Comment: I think if you set `countNodes (Leaf a) = 1`, you will count all Node+all leafs, but i just want to count all nodes :)

Answer (score 3):

*Let the machine do the work*. Both of your counting functions are an instance of a much more general concept, *folding*. I'm going to write a small amount of code to fold up a tree, and use it to define both of your desired counting functions for free.

I'm going start by generalising your `Tree` type slightly, to be internally labelled with `b`s at `Node`s and externally labelled with `a`s at `Leaf`s.

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Node (Tree a b) b (Tree a b)
```

Your original `Tree` type is equivalent to `Tree a ()`.

This version of `Tree` is an instance of a useful class called [`Bifoldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifoldable.html). `Bifoldable` generalises [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) to work over datatypes with two type parameters.

```
instance Bifoldable Tree where
    bifoldMap f g (Leaf a) = f a
    bifoldMap f g (Node l x r) = bifoldMap f g l `mappend` g x `mappend` bifoldMap f g r
```

`bifoldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> (b -> m) -> Tree a b -> m` collapses a `Tree` down into a single value using a [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html). It identifies all the `a`s and `b`s in the tree, applies `f` or `g` to them to get an `m`, then uses `mappend` to squish the resulting structure into a single value.

This is the only nontrivial bit of code I'm going to write. Everything else is just manipulating types; `countLeaves` and `countNodes` will both get squeezed through the toothpaste tube of `bifoldMap`. (There are some [Template Haskell helpers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-TH.html) to generate instances of `Bifoldable` for you, so you don't even need to write the code that does the hard work!)

Every `Bifoldable` is automatically a `Foldable` in two ways. [The `WrappedBifunctor` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Wrapped.html) makes a `Bifoldable` into a `Foldable` which aggregates its second argument.

```
newtype WrappedBifunctor p a b = WrapBifunctor { unwrapBifunctor :: p a b }

instance Bifoldable p => Foldable (WrappedBifunctor p a) where
    foldMap f = bifoldMap (const mempty) f . unwrapBifunctor
```

This is already enough to give us a way to count nodes. Counting nodes is the same as counting occurrences of the `b` type parameter, which is exactly what `length` does for any `Foldable`. All we have to do is wrap the tree to get something `Foldable`.

```
-- i lied, this is nontrivial too - but it's already in the standard library
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
length = foldl' (\c _ -> c+1) 0

countNodes :: Tree a b -> Int
countNodes = length . WrapBifunctor

ghci> let myTree = Node (Node (Leaf 'a') () (Leaf 'b')) () (Node (Leaf 'c') () (Leaf 'd'))
ghci> countNodes myTree
3
```

How about counting leaves? This time we need to count occurrences of the `a` type parameter. `WrappedBifunctor` can help here too: we can rearrange `Tree`'s parameters such that `a` is the second parameter, then wrap it up - the resulting `Foldable` instance will count `a`s instead of `b`s. For this we'll need [the `Flip` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html), which switches the parameters of its argument just like `flip` does at the value level:

```
newtype Flip p a b = Flip { runFlip :: p b a }

instance Bifoldable p => Bifoldable (Flip p) where
    bifoldMap f g = bifoldMap g f . runFlip
```

Now we can count leaves for free:

```
countLeaves :: Tree a b -> Int
countLeaves = length . WrapBifunctor . Flip

ghci> countLeaves myTree
4
```

Finally, you can count leaves *and* nodes using the [`bilength`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifoldable.html#v:bilength) function from the `Bifoldable` class.

```
bilength :: Bifoldable t => t a b -> Int
bilength = bifoldl' (\c _ -> c+1) (\c _ -> c+1) 0

countLeavesAndNodes :: Tree a b -> Int
countLeavesAndNodes = bilength
-- equivalent to, but more efficient than...
-- countLeavesAndNodes t = countLeaves t + countNodes t
```

---

Haskell's philosophy is to solve problems like this once and for all, and apply these general solutions to specific cases. Newtypes like `Flip` and `WrappedBifunctor` let us express general properties (like "every `Bifunctor` is still a `Bifunctor` after you flip its arguments") with no runtime cost. We used these properties to manipulate the type class system into writing the code to count `a`s and `b`s for us.

As you continue to learn Haskell, you'll get the hang of spotting when a program is an instance of a general pattern. Setting up general structures like the `Bifoldable` instance above quickly pays dividends in code reuse.

Comment: Why not start with catamorphisms? `cata :: (a -> r) -> (r -> b -> r -> r) -> Tree a b -> r` is the universal fold over the type you've defined; it's easy to define `bifoldMap f g = cata f (\ l v r -> l <> g v <> r)`.